# Find all $x$ such that determinant is zero .

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

$$\begin{vmatrix}x-a & a-b & b-c \\ c-a & x-b & a-c    \\ b-a & c-b & x-c \end{vmatrix} =0 $$

I began expanding but quickly gave up, i couldn't factor it.Adding or subtracting rows/columns got me nowhere because i made no zeroes.

Any idea would be helpful. Hopefuly there is a more elegant solution than expansion and brute force,if that is the only way how to factor(apart from using cubical formula) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without constraints or additional information, your determinant is:

$$-a^3+a^2 (b+c+x)-a \left(b^2+2 b (c-x)-c^2+2 c x+x^2\right)+b^3-b^2 (c+x)+b \left(c^2+2 c x-x^2\right)-c^3+c^2 x-c x^2+x^3$$

and brute force is the only way forward.  The three solutions (using the cubic equation) are:

$$\{x\to a-b+c\} \\ 
\left\{x\to b-\sqrt{-a^2+2 a c-c^2}\right\} \\
\left\{x\to
   \sqrt{-a^2+2 a c-c^2}+b\right\}$$

Comment: This problem is a part of a bigger problem, so it seems i have to find another way to solve it ,  the other two solutions show that elementary transformations wont help :(

Comment: I don't understand:  "This problem is a part of a bigger problem, so it seems i have to find another way to solve it."  Explain the "so."

Comment: I dont want to memorize the cubic formula

Comment: No need to memorize.... just use.  Anyway, good luck finding another way.  (Over and out.)

Comment: @Milan There's no need to memorise the cubic formula if you can remember the general method to solving cubics, which has been well-known for centuries (just Google). It will be rather tedious though.

Comment: Note that the value under the root is $-(a-c)^2$, so assuming we are only looking for real $x$, the last two only exist when $a = c$, and then coincide at $x = b$. This leaves the comparatively simple $x = a - b + c$, which suggests a more intuitive explanation based on the particular form of the original matrix.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether it is relevant or not, but the following slightly modified determinant has a nice factorisation:

$$\begin{vmatrix}
(x-a)  & (c-b) & (b-c) \\
(c-a)  & (x-b) & (a-c)\\
(b-a)  & (a-b) & (x-c) \\
\end{vmatrix}=(x-(a+b-c))(x-(a-b+c))(x-(-a+b+c)).$$

Comment: How did you factorize it , did you perform transformations before expanding the determinant ?

Comment: If you consider the sum of two first rows minus the third, you get the row $$\left( (x-a-b+c)\ (x-a-b+c)\ -(x-a-b+c)\right) =(x-a-b+c) (1\ 1\ -1)$$
You can do this simultaneously on the three rows considering the product:
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
-1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & -1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & -1
\end{vmatrix}
\begin{vmatrix}
(x-a) & (c-b) & (b-c)\\
(c-a) & (x-b) & (a-c)\\
(b-a) & (a-b) & (x-c)
\end{vmatrix}$$
$$=
(x-(-a+b+c))(x-(a-b+c))(x-(a+b-c))
\begin{vmatrix}
-1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & -1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & -1
\end{vmatrix}.
$$